# Redhat reporting that 443 is use, but its not

Tags: apache, redhat

I have a RHEL 7 server, and Apache won't start on it.  When I attempt to start the service, I get:

```
 httpd[8499]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 123.456.789.123:443
```

When I do a netstat -plant, I don't see anything listening on 443:

```
netstat -plant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1069/sshd 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1068/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2408/master
tcp        0      0 123.456.789.123:22      123.456.789.123:35174   ESTABLISHED 31389/sshd: tdcarte
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      12011/rpcbind
```

lsof -i tcp:443 returns no results.

Additionally, I did an nmap scan on the server in case the OS lost track of Apache's pid and couldn't report that it was already running, but nothing appears to be using 443 there, either.

I'm also getting "AH00015: Unable to open logs" at the same time, if that is indicative to anyone.  SELinux is disabled, and I've checked to make sure there is only listen statement for 443 in my conf's, and that is located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.  Any other Listen statements to 443 have been commented out.  This one is puzzling me, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: try connecting to port 443 using some other client, like 'telnet' or 'nc'

Comment: I get 'connection refused' on a telnet, which makes sense if there is no listener.

Comment: you doing all of these commands as root or some other user? try root (or use sudo)

Comment: Everything as root.